# Set a view determined previously in the XML file

Tags: android, xml, view

I've a View declared in the XML file, and I want to define it by code, but when I establish it nothing is shown. Can you help me?

This is my XML file:

[...]

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/marco_container"
        style="@style/wrapFull"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[...]

And I define it by this way:

```
setContentView(R.layout.marco);
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.marco_container);
view.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.prueba, null);
```

I tried to declare it by this way too:

```
view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.prueba, null);
```

This is prueba.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:text="Prueba" style="@style/wrapContent" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste the contents of R.layout.prueba

Comment: Possible duplication of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221205/define-a-view-of-a-xml-by-code)

Comment: It's not duplicated, I used a Linear Layout, but with different problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a View view. It's your custom View, just create a custom view that extends FrameLayout and inside the constructor inflate your view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER...);
View view = inflater.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.prueba, this);
```

and inside your main xml put :

```
<com.my.path.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/marco_container"
    style="@style/wrapFull"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in your class :

```
setContentView(R.layout.marco);
CustomView view = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.marco_container);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way:

```
View view2 = view.inflate(this, R.layout.prueba, null);
((ViewGroup)view).addView(view2);
```

Of course `view` must be some kind of `ViewGroup` (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.marco);
LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.marco_container);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.prueba, li, false);
li.addView(view);
```